# list the Data in sequential order according to the Date

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am learning cakePHP 1.26.
I got some sample data in a Table Testing which consists of two fields:
(there is not primary key in this sample Table)

### Data | Date

Hello     |  2010-07-1 15:11:11
World   | 2010-07-1 11:01:01
Hi there  | 2010-07-02 11:36:11

I need to find out their position number according to the Date when they were written into the Database, 
i.e. which of them came first and which of them came second.
But I don't know if there is a component in cakePHP that can help me solve the question.

It is easy to list them out according to the Date and number each record manually when there are only a few records in the Database,but when the reocrds grow, it will be difficult for humans to do it this way:

Record 1: Hi there
Record 2: Hello
Record 3: World

Comment: why not add an autoincrement `id`?then it would be the order number.

Comment: @SpawnCxy. At a particular period, there may be more than 1 record written to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller

```
$this->set('results', $this->MyTable->find('all', array('order'=>'date_field')));
```

In model

```
foreach($reuslts as $key=>$value){
  echo "Record ".$key.": ".$value['MyTable']['name']
}
```